# How are 'irreducible' elements called in module theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a 'nice' ring (whatever that means, I guess commutative with unity $1_R$) and let $M$ be an $R$--module. Is there a name for the following property?

An element $m \in M$ is called ... iff. whenever we have $m = rm'$ for some $r \in R, m' \in M$ (i.e. if it is a multiple of some other element) then $r$ is a unit.

This seems to correspond to the concept of irreducibility when $M=R$.

Thanks,

FW

Comment: I've never seen that, iirc. That's close to not being in the radical of the module, though.

Comment: I've never run into a specific choice of terminology either. I guess the hope would be to write every element of $M$ as an "irreducible" element of $M$ and a product of irreducible elements in $R$?